# jQuery mobile utf-8 encoding not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, utf-8, character-encoding

Basically what is happeing to me is that a text like "Ubicación" (spanish) is showing as "Ubicaciyn" same problem for every text with '

I am using this `<meta charset="utf-8">` and I opened the file on note++ and save it as encoding in UTF-8.

If I take out the jquerymobile.js the problem is gone.

**UPDATE**

When I remove the jquery mobile stylesheet the problem is gone.. someone knows why?

**FIXED**

I fixed the problem, is a rare behaviour, what i had to do was to delete the all font-family properties from the default jquery mobile css. I dont know why but that fixed the problem, then I added a new css after that one with my specific font-familt and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

Please try with complete meta tag for utf-8 encoding.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I fixed the problem, is a rare behaviour, what i had to do was to delete the all font-family properties from the default jquery mobile css. I dont know why but that fixed the problem, then I added a new css after that one with my specific font-familt and it worked!

Comment: Maybe default fonts set in font-family don't support Spanish characters. Glad to hear you fixed it. Cheers!